# Html Helper textboxfor is not returning appropriate HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am doing the textbox code below but for some reason I am not getting the appropriate textbox being formulated.

Here is what I have:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="@Model.Options[i].Text">@Model.Options[i].Text</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.Options[i].StringValue, new { name = Model.Options[i].Id, @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
    </div>
}
```

Here is what my HTML output looks like

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control"  name="Options[0].StringValue" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
    </div>
```

I was under the presumption that the code I have in my razor HTML helper would create a html textbox with the name equal to my model option id. Why am I getting Options_0 as the name?

Comment: Well, you didn't specify `i` in either parameter to the textboxfor, so why would you expect it to show up in the name attribute of the textbox?

Comment: what do you mean I didn't specify i? @Model.Options[i].Id is in the textboxfor

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Id`.  If I pass `Model.Address` to the textboxfor, I expect my textbox to be given a name attribute of "Address", right?  If I pass `Model.Options[i].StringValue` to the textboxfor, I expect my textbox to be given a name of `Model.Options[i].StringValue`, where the actual value of `I` is substituted.

Comment: I would expect the Model.Options[i].Id would give the name of the id. So if I have the id of 2 then i would expect name="2"

Comment: But why would you expect that, if `Model.Address` names your textbox "Address", not "12345 Anywhere Street"?  Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Hmm I simply want a textbox that is named an id number and I want that value that a person types in to be set to my models StringValue. That way I can dynamically create questions with the name id (unique) and have the answers go to my StringValue model.

Comment: You could always just write out the `input` element without using the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use for this **@Html.TextBox()**, not **@Html.TextBoxFor()**